# jQuery Fancy Box pdf in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, pdf, fancybox

I'm using jQuery Fancy Box to display a PDF when triggered. It works in Firefox and Chrome, but not IE. The Fancy Box comes up and displays as it should as big as the pdf is and everything, but there is a little red x in the top left corner of the box like it couldn't load the whole document.

Here is my JS initiating the Fancy box:

```
    //initialize fancybox for PDFs
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.pdf").click(function() {
        $.fancybox({
            'width': '70%',
            'height': '99%',
            'autoSize': false,
            'content': '<embed src="'+this.href+'#nameddest=self&page=1&view=FitH,0&zoom=0,0,0" type="application/pdf" height="99%" width="99%" />',
            'onClosed': function() {
                $("#fancybox-inner").empty();
            }
        });
        return false;
    }); // pdf 
}); // ready
```

Comment: Check that you have a proper `DOCTYPE` and it is the very first line of your document.

Comment: yes I am using HTML5 so my doctype is <!DOCTYPE html>

Comment: maybe you would need to re-install the Adobe reader plugin for IE

Comment: Hello, are you get a solution to this problem?